# Giving a transformation of a random variable a distribution in WinBUGS

Tags: winbugs

For instance, it is possible to write the following relationship in WinBUGS? If so how?

X/2 ~ dnorm(0,1)

The above code generates an error.

Note that X ~2*dnorm(0,1) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a node as any function of a distribution (or several distributions), but you must do it via intermediate nodes using deterministic relationships e.g.:

```
norm_var ~ dnorm(0,1)
X <- norm_var * 2
```

If you set initial values manually, make sure you do this for norm_var and not X.